# Ajax jquery live validation for uniqueness of entries

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, validation

Is there any way to validate the availability entries, lets say username, live i.e validate as you type?
Basically i've a database table with a unique field 'category name' and a form to insert data in database. I'm using ajax to check availability of category name and pretty much successful on that, but what i want is live validation, i.e not using .onkeyup() or .blur() or some other function like that. Checking if 'category name' is already listed on table while user is typing name??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the `input` event and fire off an AJAX request that sends a query to the database table. Also, make sure the previously sent AJAX request is cancelled before sending a new one to avoid race condition.

**P.S:** I'm not quite certain about the browser compatibility of the event. It might not work with old browsers (e.g IE 8 and lower).